# How do you revoke a Firebase token generated for CI?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I need to revoke the Firebase token generated for CI. However I can't figure out how to do that.

[Firebase details how you can generate a token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems)

`firebase login:ci`

And also how to revoke a token:

`firebase logout --token TOKEN`

However I don't know what the variable for `TOKEN` is. Firebase doesn't seem to generate an ID when you create one and I can't see any CLI command to list active tokens.

How can I revoke a token without knowing what its ID is?

Answer (score 0):

`TOKEN` is the CI token generated by `firebase login:ci` that you want to revoke and not any ID.

Comment: I don't have a copy of that token though - it was put into the CI system and for security purposes, the CI doesn't expose it so there's no way to know what it actually is